# Javascript automatic popup based on time of day

Tags: javascript, popup

I need to create a popup window that open on page load AND only between 11am and 7pm EST.
I have the auto pop up working, but am having trouble adding the time variance.
Please advise.
EDITED

```
    <!--chat-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var currentTime = new Date((new Date()).toUTCString());
    var startTime = new Date((new Date()).toUTCString());
    var endTime = new Date((new Date()).toUTCString());

    startTime.setUTCHours(8);
    endTime.setUTCHours(19);

    //set times to EST. (UTC -5)
    currentTime.setHours(currentTime.getHours() - 5);
    startTime.setHours(startTime.getHours() - 5);
    endTime.setHours(endTime.getHours() - 5);

    //code to determine your variables goes here
    var mylink = "https://mylink.com";
    var windowname = "Chat Client";

    if (currentTime < endTime && currentTime > startTime) {
      popup(mylink, windowname);
    }
  });

 function popup(mylink, windowname)
{
if (! window.focus)return true;
var href;
if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
   href=mylink;
else
   href=mylink.href;
window.open(href, windowname, 'width=470,height=700,scrollbars=yes');
return false;
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that most browsers will block a popup window on load.

Comment: Thanks RoToRa - I explained the exact same thing - but the client repeatably requested to make this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//bad code removed to save space
```

EDIT:

To work in any timezone:

```
//bad code removed to save space
```

UPDATED:

Added jquery tags and function definition to demonstrate code structuring as per request.

UPDATE2:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
  var currentTime = toUTC(new Date());
  var startTime = toUTC(new Date());
  var endTime = toUTC(new Date());

  startTime.setHours(11);
  startTime.setMinutes(0);
  startTime.setSeconds(0);
  endTime.setHours(19);
  endTime.setMinutes(0);
  endTime.setSeconds(0);

  //set times to EST. (UTC -4)
  currentTime.setHours(currentTime.getHours() - 4);

  //code to determine your variables goes here
  //var mylink = 
  //var windowname = 

  if (currentTime < endTime && currentTime > startTime) {
    popup();
  }
});

function popup() {
  //put function code here
  $('body').append("Here is some text");
} 

function toUTC(inDate) {
  inDate.setMinutes(inDate.getMinutes() + inDate.getTimezoneOffset());
  return inDate;
}
```

And here it is in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CmnTd/).

Comment: Forgive me as I am not as seasoned as some, but do I need to add my code after this....and if so, how exactly should it be structured?

Comment: Edited my response.  Hopefully that answers your question.  If you have more questions please let me know!

Comment: Thanks Chockleyc!  I tried that originally and the auto load still happens - even though it is outside of the time indicated....I posted the new code above for reference.

Comment: You need to take the onload part out of the body tag.  The javascript is now doing that for you.  By having it in the body tag as well it is rendering the javascript completely useless. Cheers!
Edit: Take the onload out and make sure you set your two variables inside the javascript code.

Comment: It still will not work properly.  How does it determine the time? (maybe that is the problem??)

Comment: No worries.  I appreciate your help.  BUT - it still will not create a the popup????

Comment: Please update your current code in the question so that I can take a look at it.  It is working for me.

Comment: I got it working!  Thanks so much chocleyc.  They are now requesting the time be pulled from the server and not the local pc.  Is this something you could assist with?

Comment: Sure, but message me on here rather than continuing this already lengthy comment thread.  I will reply after work.

Answer (score 0):

But it's only work with local time.

```
var date = new Date();
var hours = date.getHours();

if(hours > 11 && hours < 19)
{
   // show pop-up
}
```